# In-app purchases arn't being charged in Android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I was using a friend's phone to test my in-app purchases and it said "This is a test order, you will not be charged." which made since because it was in beta.  but then I published the app and it is still saying that on my friend's phone.  Is that just for his phone, or is this a problem with everyone using the app??  I made sure that my friend downloaded the app from the Google play store so that she didn't still have the old APK.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me but then my friend ordered something and paid for it, i think test users that are listed will always be able to make test purchases

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the user's email (Google email Id) as a test user under the Settings -> License Testing section in developer console, then the purchases made by that account will be test purchases. Remove the email and the user can make real purchases even if he has opted in as alpha-beta tester.